# angularjs $$hashkey not add in Json

Tags: json, angularjs, csv

I extract data from csv file and I put them in JsonArray like this :

```
var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var listeParticipant = {};
var participants = [];
listeParticipant.participants = participants;

  for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length-1; i++) {
      var data = allTextLines[i].split(';');
      var dossard = data[0];
      var nom = data[1];
      var prenom = data[2];

      var participant = {
        "nom": data[1] , 
        "prenom": data[2],
        "dossard": data[0]
      }
    listeParticipant.participants.push(participant);
  }

$scope.listeParticipants = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listeParticipant.participants));
```

where csv is a file .csv. When is print   $scope.listeParticipants I have a JSON ( seems right) but not $$hashkey is generate . What's wrong in my code ?

```
Object {participants: Array[9]}
           participants: Array[9]
           0: Object
           dossard: "1"
           nom: "Paul"
           prenom: "Henry"
           __proto__: Object
           1: Object
           2: Object
           3: Object
```

Comment: why the overhead of first stringifying array and then parse to JSON? Makes no sense.

Comment: right. But when I do $scope.listeParticipants =listeParticipant.participants I have the same result , no $$hashkey. That why I try to make JSON.parse

Comment: `JSON.parse` is a native javascript method that has nothing to do with angular so why would it add angular properties?

Comment: Fine I do $scope.listeParticipants = listeParticipant.participants and It's work.

Comment: Fine I do $scope.listeParticipants = listeParticipant.participants and sometimes it's work but not always. I think I need to review all my code, not just the transformation cvs to Json. Thanks  for all ;)